# In Azure Devops, should I create a YAML file per branch or just a master YAML that controls all?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to come up with the best practice to handle my releases.

Option A is to have 1 YAML file in the main branch that controls all deployments.

- If the main branch is updated, then it will deploy all stages (test, preprod, prod).
- If any other branch is updated/created, it should only execute the dev stage.

Option B is to just create a custom YAML file for the main branch and use another common YML file for all other branches to achieve the same behavior mentioned before.

Comment: I recommend you check out the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) parameter.

Comment: @rlsi2q, have you checked Maytham's suggestion below? It's a good choice to use one yaml to deploy all stages but use parameters to control the stage which environment to deploy to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-fit solution, but Option A is the practical approach with few conditions.

When creating a feature branch you trigger CI that builds and tests. At some point, you want to QA your feature and you can manually deploy it to the test stage. I would suggest using parameters with 3 mentioned environments.

The following Example is one pipeline that has multistage both CI and CD:

[image]

[image]

If it passes the QA test, then you want to merge it to the main and deploy it to pre-production and if it still passes that, you can make an approval gate to deploy it to production. In this case, no need to deploy to the test environment again.

With that said, you need to make an overall strategy for your CI/CD. And the above examples and answer is inspiration for one way of doing it.